# Why does the following Python 3 "if" work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing a quick test on the "if" statement and the following code fragment results in the print producing output as expected.

**Case 1**

```
x = True
if x:
    print("Roses are red")
```

Results in >>> Roses are red, in the interpreter

Also:

```
type(x)
>>> <class 'bool'>
```

As expected.

Then I tried:

**Case 2**

```
x = "True"
if x:
    print("Roses are red")
```

Again I got the result: Roses are red

and :

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

Can someone explain in the second case why the "if condition is satisfied" (if that is an appropriate way to describe the situation) and the print() is executed?

I would have thought the correct operation would be something like

```
if <expression>:
    <do this>
```

where "do this" is executed **only** when "expression" evaluates to the **Boolean** value True. Why is "do this" executed when "expression" is a **string**?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string "True" is [truthy](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) meaning that it evaluates to true in your if condition.